# Database (mysql) connection is working but jdeveloper can't launch my application

Tags: java, mysql, jdeveloper

I have a project here on JDeveloper 11.1.2.3.39.62.76.1). I've already done the Create Database Connection Wizard and everything is working fine, but when i try to launch my application this is what i get:

```
Caused By: weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourceSystemException:
Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver     
   at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.JDBCUtil.parseException(JDBCUtil.java:301)
   at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionEnvFactory.loadDriver(ConnectionEnvFactory.java:75)
   at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionEnvFactory.<init>(ConnectionEnvFactory.java:131)
   at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionPool.initPooledResourceFactory(ConnectionPool.java:712)
   at weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.start(ResourcePoolImpl.java:235)
```

Does anyone can shed a light? I've already included the mysql connector jar.

Comment: What application are you using?

Comment: maybe: http://techiecook.wordpress.com/2010/10/08/weblogic-runtime-libraries-mysql-connector-example/

Comment: @ethrbunny already did that, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the jdbc jar file for mySQL to your embedded WebLogic lib directory.

Comment: Thank you very very very much! If i ever meet you i may give you a cookie!