# Error deploying adf application on integrated weblogic server using mysql database

Tags: oracle-adf

I am getting below error while running adf application on integrated weblogice server using my sql database.

I have tried to place mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin jar file in different directories without any luck.

also looked at [Database (mysql) connection is working but jdeveloper can't launch my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441604/database-mysql-connection-is-working-but-jdeveloper-cant-launch-my-applicatio)

and

http://techiecook.wordpress.com/2010/10/08/weblogic-runtime-libraries-mysql-connector-example/

but could not find the exact location to place the jar file.

```
          12:28:34 AM] Deploying Application...
          <12-Jun-2013 00:28:35 o'clock BST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID '1370993314886' for task '0'. Error is: 'weblogic.application.ModuleException: '
          weblogic.application.ModuleException: 
            at weblogic.jdbc.module.JDBCModule.prepare(JDBCModule.java:302)
            at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:199)
            at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:517)
            at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
            at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:159)
            Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
          Caused By: weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourceSystemException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
            at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.JDBCUtil.parseException(JDBCUtil.java:301)
            at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionEnvFactory.loadDriver(ConnectionEnvFactory.java:75)
            at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionEnvFactory.<init>(ConnectionEnvFactory.java:131)
            at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionPool.initPooledResourceFactory(ConnectionPool.java:712)
            at weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.start(ResourcePoolImpl.java:235)
            Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
          >
```

please help.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that as well as all of the fluffy around copying the mysql jar to the weblogic dir, it is also necessary to ensure that the library is exported from your Model project properties.

i.e. Project Properties -> Libraries and ClassPath -> Add Library (Ensure exported)

I hope this helps